# probability of encountering 5 heads

Tags: probability

find probability that during a process of tossing coins repeatedly one will encounter a run of $5$ consecutive heads before encountering $2$ tails.

I started by assuming,

$H$= probability that this event occurs when first toss was Heads

$T$= probability that this event occurs when first toss was Tails

What to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At any point in time as you keep tossing the coin, you can be in 5 different states. Either your last throw was a T, or your last throws were a streak of 1, 2, 3 or 4 H. (You're in a sixth state just as you start the game, but we'll skip that one for now.)

In each state, you have some probability of winning, losing, or transitioning into one of the other 4 states. For each state, there is also a probability of eventually winning from that point on. I'll call those evental winning probabilities $P(T)$ and $P(1H), P(2H), P(3H), P(4H)$.

From here we can set up equations (using the law of total probability). For instance, if you're in the 4H state, then there is a 50% chance you'll win on the next throw, and a 50% chance you'll enter state T. Thus
$$
P(4H) = \frac12 + \frac12P(T)
$$
Similarily, if you're in state T, you have a 50% chance of losing, and a 50% chance of entering state 1H. Thus
$$
P(T) = \frac12P(1H)
$$
You can similarily set up equations for $P(1H), P(2H)$ and $P(3H)$. You now have five equations and five unknowns, so this may be solved.

Once you've done that, you can look at the state you're in as you start the game, and see that the probability of winning from there is
$$
\frac12P(T) + \frac12P(1H)
$$

Comment: can you solve for just one more state say P(2H) ? please.

Comment: okay wait. is this correct- P(2H) = 1/2 P(T) + 1/2 P(3H)

Comment: @tanya Exactly! probability $\frac12$ of getting tails and transitioning to state $T$, $\frac12$ of getting heads and transitioning to state $3H$.

Comment: thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

To be discerned are the following states:

- 0) No tosses are made yet.
- 1) $H$
- 2) $HH$
- 3) $HHH$
- 4) $HHHH$
- 5) $T$

Here e.g. $HH$ stands for the state that the last two tosses were
heads and before that there was a tail or there were no tosses at
all.

For $i=0,1,2,3,4,5$ let $p_{i}$ denote the probability on the
event that is described in your question under condition that we start
in state $i$.

Then to be found is $p_{0}$ and we have the following equalities:

- $p_{i}=\frac{1}{2}p_{i+1}+\frac{1}{2}p_{5}$ for $i=0,1,2,3$
- $p_{4}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}p_{5}$
- $p_{5}=\frac{1}{2}p_{1}$

These equalities enable you to find $p_0$ and the result will be:$$p_0=\frac3{34}$$